# sql query: select people with same name ascending by age

Tags: sql, mysql

Have 2 table

```
1st {id_city,name } 
2nd table {id_ctz,name,sname,age,id_city}
```

need selected full information (name(city),name,sname,age) people with same name ascending by age?

Have tried:

```
select city.name,citizen.name,age 
from citizen,city where city.id_city = citizen.id_city and citizen.name = '%s' 
order by age asc
```

input variable is name

Comment: select city.name,citizen.name,age from citizen,city where city.id_city = citizen.id_city and citizen.name = '%s' order by age asc

Comment: @alexandr: And what's the problem with that?

Comment: i need not only rows where  name is %s all another rows

Comment: @alexandr: 'i need not only rows where name is %s all another rows' I'm sorry, I don't understand what this means. Can you give some example data and your desired output for this data?

Comment: name=%s age 30 city=NY
name=%s age 41 city=SA

thats it all another row dont output
I need first data row will by name = %s asc by age and after will be go all another

Comment: @alexandr: It's difficult to read. Edit your question instead of using comments. And use formatting. That will make things clearer.

Comment: The trick to getting a good answer is writing a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want all rows to be returned, and you want people with some name first, sorted by age. Afterwards you want all other rows. This query will do that:

```
SELECT city.name, citizen.name, citizen.age 
FROM citizen
JOIN city ON city.id_city = citizen.id_city
ORDER BY citizen.name <> 'some_name', citizen.age
```

Comment: It work Thanks Mark Byers !!!! i dont now about that
 ORDER BY citizen.name <> 'varible'
Thanks again!

Comment: Nice guess! I like lucky charms

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could do with the (lack of) information given.

```
SELECT *
FROM 1st a
JOIN 2nd b ON a.id_city=b.id_city
WHERE a.name = 'same'
ORDER BY b.age ASC
```

Note: Don't actually use the * as your output columns. Use the actual names.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c2.name AS CityName,
c1.name AS CitizenName,
c1.age  AS CitizenAge
from citizen as C1 
inner join city as C2 on C1.id_city = c2.id_city
where c1.name = 'frank' 
order by c1.age asc
```

Comment: it will be output only rows where name is 'Frank' but i need all another after

Comment: @alexandr: you stated that you wanted 'people with same name accending by age'. Perhaps can you **edit your question** to include sample data, and then the results that you'd expect from the query?

Answer (score 0):

Is what you're looking for really help with how to pass a parameter to a query? In that case, your problem is ='%s'. You need to remove the single quotes. In a TSQL stored procedure, it would be = @s instead. MySQL I'm not sure about (you've got both tags), and if you're using something other than stored procedures to do a parameterized query, it would depend on the data provider you're using.